# Akka cluster node not joining: stuck with "new incarnation of existing member trying to join"

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I have a local node trying to join my production cluster in order to monitor it.

It worked well for a few days, but today, I'm starting it (because nodes in the cluster seem to have problems to connect each other) but the node is not joining.

I'm subscribing to the cluster with `InitialStateAsEvents`, but I don't get messages anymore.

The logs in the production nodes are saying this regularly:

```
New incarnation of existing member [Member(address = akka.tcp://application@127.0.0.1:2000, status = Down)] is trying to join. Existing will be removed from the cluster and then new member will be allowed to join.
```

However, I unsubscribe the node after leaving the application with

```
override def postStop(): Unit = {
  cluster.down(cluster.selfAddress)
  cluster.unsubscribe(self)
}
```

Comment: what version of Akka are you using? There has been some improvements over the last releases regarding this type of behavior.

Comment: I'm using the version 2.4.16